# Saving file information to database and comparing

Tags: java, file, directory, compare

I want to write application for detecting changes in directory. For example I want to save information about files in database (create version of directory files), and then compare actual content of directory with given version. I need to check informations like file size, file name. The question is, how to know which file is which? I mean attributes like name, size etc. changes so how to know if it's the same file which was changed and not another one? Heard about WatcherService but it is comparing changes at runtime, I want to fetch my saved in database file informations and compare against actual.